# How can I get `value` by clicking from the child tag?

Tags: reactjs

I need to get `value` from tag `p` by clicking on parent `div`.

How can I do that?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Industry extends Component {

  state = {
    industry: ["Финансы", "Развлечения"]
  }

  onIndustry(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Profile__otrasl">
          // CLICK HERE
          <div className="Profile__otrasl_block"
           onClick={this.onIndustry.bind(this)}
      >
            <span className="icon-icon-hat">
              <span className="path1"></span><span className="path2"></span><span className="path3"></span><span
              className="path4"></span><span className="path5"></span>
            </span>
        // GET VALUE FROM HERE
        <p>Мода и стиль</p>
      </div>
      // CLICK HERE
      <div className="Profile__otrasl_block"
           onClick={this.onIndustry.bind(this)}>
            <span className="icon-icon-med-bag">
            <span className="path1"></span><span className="path2"></span><span className="path3"></span><span
              className="path4"></span><span className="path5"></span><span className="path6"></span><span
              className="path7"></span><span className="path8"></span><span className="path9"></span>
            </span>
        // GET VALUE FROM HERE
        <p>Медицина</p>
      </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Industry;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I think if you have many elements, you should try it like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Industry extends Component {
  state = {
    industry: ['Финансы', 'Развлечения'],
    list: [
            {
              value: 'Мода и стиль', 
              icons: ['path1','path2', 'path3', 'path4', 'path5']
            },
            {
              value: 'Медицина', 
              icons: ['path2','path3', 'path4', 'path5', 'path6', 
                      'path7', 'path8', 'path9']
            },
          ]
  };


  onIndustry = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Profile__otrasl">
          {this.state.list.map((data) => {
            return (
              <div className="Profile__otrasl_block" onClick={() => this.onIndustry(data)}>
                <span className="icon-icon-hat">
                  {data.icons.map(icon => {
                       return <span className={icon} />
                  })}
                </span>
                <p>{data.value}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Industry;
```

and then, you can use **this.setState({list: [...]})** to update the component

Comment: <span className="icon-icon-hat">
                  <span className="path1" />
                  <span className="path2" />
                  <span className="path3" />
                  <span className="path4" />
                  <span className="path5" />
                </span>
this code should change, and i can't do this with your example='

Comment: if I could transfer the html in a variable, then this would work

Comment: I copied this code from your question. I don't know what you want to change

Comment: look at my code, there two elements with different html in it

Comment: it's possible but may be i can to do like in jquery $( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" )  or it impossible ?

Comment: sorry...react can't do that like jquery. because react depends on data, not DOM. 
if my answer is helpful, please upvote, thank you :) @СтасРябцев

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a ref to p tag and then onClick get the value inside p tag from the ref.

```
<p ref={(el) => this.el = el}>Мода и стиль</p>

 onIndustry(e) {
    console.log(e)
    const value = this.el && this.el.innerText;
  }
```

With multiple cases make a separate component and pass value for p tag and click handler through props:-

```
function Profile({ value, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div className="Profile__otrasl_block"
      onClick={() => handleClick(value)}>
      <span className="icon-icon-med-bag">
        <span className="path1"></span><span className="path2"></span><span className="path3"></span><span
          className="path4"></span><span className="path5"></span><span className="path6"></span><span
            className="path7"></span><span className="path8"></span><span className="path9"></span>
      </span>
      // GET VALUE FROM HERE
      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then in parent component change onIndustry to receive value param:-

```
onIndustry(value) {
    console.log(value)
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Profile value="Мода и стиль" handleClick={onIndustry} />
        <Profile value="some other value" handleClick={onIndustry} />
        <Profile value="some more different value" handleClick={onIndustry} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works fine, but what should i do if i have multiply elements ?

Comment: Is the data coming from a server or its hard coded and you know upfront how many elements there will be?

Comment: its hard coded about 20 elements. In jquery i can use child selector and get value, but in your code I need write 20 times for every element, i want solution like in jquery

Comment: In order to get child ref from the div you will have to add ref to every single parent div. You cannot get ref to parent div from a click handler and access child. And if you are using this same structure 20 different times you should probably make a separate component for this and that will make things quite simple.

Comment: I also thought about this solution, but there is another problem, as you can see the tag span are different everywhere, and then I will have to send html markup to each element

Comment: There is a concept of renderProp which is a pattern for specifying what to render. So yes you will have to send html as prop but thats fine and a pattern used widely. Please take a look at the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you want to get vale from `<p>` tag and it represents a state for component then you should add a stat for it and use its value from state

```
class Industry extends Component {

    state = {
    industry: ["Финансы", "Развлечения"],
    pState : "Мода и стиль"
    }

    onIndustry(e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(this.state.pState)
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="Profile__otrasl">
            // CLICK HERE
            <div className="Profile__otrasl_block"
                onClick={this.onIndustry.bind(this)}
            >
                <span className="icon-icon-hat">
                    <span className="path1"></span><span className="path2"></span><span className="path3"></span><span
                    className="path4"></span><span className="path5"></span>
                </span>
            // NEED GET VALUE FROM HERE
            <p>{this.state.pState}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default Industry;
```

Comment: you can convert `pState` to array or as @cEeNiKc suggested make one more react component and pass value as prop